# Distinct keyword not working while selecting multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this :

```
select distinct po_no, rescan_status 
from T_PoHeader 
order by po_no
```

My output is like this:

```
po_no   rescan_status
---------------------
P-01    True
P-02    True
p-03    False
p-04    False
p-04    True
```

Here my `po_no` is showing duplicates if I use `distinct` keyword. I want to only show distinct `po_no`.

Comment: its already distinct of both the columns.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to have.  Your results look fine to me.

Comment: So what it should show for p-04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results look fine to me.  I don't see any duplicate rows.

Speculation might be that you want `po_no` to be unique on each row.  If so, use aggregation and an aggregation function:

```
select po_no, max(rescan_status) as rescan_status
from T_PoHeader 
group by po_no
order by po_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `distinct` keyword works over all the columns you select. Being that you selected '**rescan_status**' which has one row true and one row false for the same '**po_no**' there are two 'distinct' combinations.

Remove '**rescan_status**' to get only Distinct '**po_no**'.

Comment: So your going to get duplicate for 'p-04', because, it is a distinct combination. If you remove 'rescan_status' you will see only one.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte(po_no,rescan_status)
AS
(
SELECT 'P-01','True'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'P-02','True'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'p-03','False' UNION ALL
SELECT 'p-04','False' UNION ALL
SELECT 'p-04','True'
)
SELECT po_no,rescan_status From
(
select po_no,rescan_status ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By po_no order by po_no) Seq from cte
)Dt
where Dt.Seq=1
```